# Own brightness script, problem with missing ']'

Tags: 14.04, bash, dell, brightness

I'm starting my adventure with Ubuntu ( I'm a MS's kid :D) and I would like to create my own scripts for controlling the brightness. I know all about the xbindkeys, and how does it works, but there is a problem with my script, which won't work properly. Terminal says, that there is an error in the line 5: [: missing ']'. Can anyone tell me whats wrong with that code? Thanks in advance!

```
#!/bin/bash
brightness=$(cat "/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness")
a=$((brightness+2))
if [ "$brightness" -lt 3]
then
    echo $a >> /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness
fi
```

Comment: Other option is to run Cuttlefish to execute scripts AND control the governor on battery change. If you are interested I can help out with all the necessary tools.

Comment: @paradise407 `echo $a >> /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness` - this script almost certainly needs to be run as root. Is it? And you shouldn't append to the file. Such files are meant to be overwritten with a value. Use `>` instead of `>>`.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
if [ "$brightness" -lt 3]
```

there needs to be a space before the `]`:

```
if [ "$brightness" -lt 3 ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it's "working", because there is no error in the code, but still brightness wont go up...